# Replacing repeated groups of characters using regex

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

In R, I have a string where it contains repeated groups of characters:

```
testString <- "Hi hi missing u lollol hahahahalol sillybilly haaaaa!"
```

I'm trying to use a gsub regex to replace repeated groups of characters within each word to produce the following output:

```
"Hi hi missing u lol halol sillybilly haaaaa!"
```

I've tried the following line but it isn't producing the right output:

```
gsub("[[:blank:]](.+?){2,}[[blank]]\\1",
replacement="\\1", testString, perl=TRUE)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why `haaaaa`? Maybe `haaa`? Why is it expected to be unmodified?

Comment: I want to keep repeating single characters together (e.g. 'aa' is allowed). However, repeating multiple strings are not ('haha' becomes 'ha'; 'haahaa' becomes 'haa').

Comment: you'll need a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Comment: this gets pretty close... `gsub('((([A-Za-z]+)[^\\1]+)\\2+)', '\\3', testString)
`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you help diagnose what's wrong with my approach? Any chance to salvage it?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: It won't work because you cannot put a backreference into a bracket expression.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so what's happening there? since it compiled, I guess `[^\\1]` was just ignoring `\ ` and `1` as characters?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Yes, since you are using a TRE regex, `"[^\\1]"` matches any char but a ``\`` and `1`. If you use a PCRE regex, it matches any char but a SOH char then. See [this R demo](http://ideone.com/6jxNMY). However, this approach does not work when fixed - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SncsPY/3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match repeated consecutive word chars and skip them, and then handle all other repeated consecutive chars with a solution like

```
x <- "Hi hi missing u lollol hahahahalol sillybilly haaaaa!"
gsub("(\\w)\\1+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\w+?)\\2+", "\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SncsPY/1) and an [online R demo](http://ideone.com/jG7HbV)

*Details*:

- `(\\w)\\1+(*SKIP)(*F)` - match and capture a word char (with `(\\w)`, this can be adjusted) and then 1+ ocurrences of this same char (with `\\1+`) and then the whole text is discarded and the engine goes on to search for another match after the end of the match (with the [PCRE `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) sequence)
- `|` - or
- `(\\w+?)\\2+` - 1 or more word chars, as few as possible, are captured into Group 2 (with `(\\w+?)`) and then 1+ occurrences of the same value are matched (with `\\2+`).

The replacement is just the Group 2  value.

Comment: This was a really good learning example for me (for one, I had never seen *SKIP or *F before). I'm still working through this to check it out.

Comment: @SimonsSchus: Why is the output not expected? It is `Hi hi missing u lol halol sillybilly haaaaa!`.

Comment: Because I'm a fool, and I was putting the wrong testString string in! I will reassess and try to understand.

Comment: BTW, Michael's solution, when fixed, [does not produce the required outout](https://regex101.com/r/SncsPY/3).

Comment: This approach works. I'm having trouble with legitimate words with repetition (e.g. banana). I could likely update the expression to require matches only when there are two or more repetitions (e.g. 'hahaha' becomes 'ha', but 'haha' is retained as 'haha').

Comment: The example of my above 'banana' suggestion using the code by @Wiktor Stribiżew is: `gsub("(\\w)\\1+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\w+?)\\2{2,}", "\\2", testString, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @SimonsSchus: You may add the words to the SKIP-FAIL part: `"(?:banana|(\\w)\\1+)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\\w+?)\\2+"`. But I also tested with `{2,}` at the beginning, before posting the answer. Adjust as needed.

Comment: beware of "ratatat" and "logogogue"